# Using mod_rewrite with a single GET variable

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite a url such as:

`example.com/var?id=0&blah=foo`
**to**
`example.com/?test=var&id=0&blah=foo`

---

So far I have this in my .htaccess:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ?api_call=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which rewrites `var` into `?test=var` but the remaining get variables are left off.

---

How can this be changed to include the other GET vars?

Comment: Your rule looks fine. Do you have other rules also?

Comment: @anubhava Nope that's the only one.

Comment: Ok for testing try this: `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ?test=$1 [L,QSA,R]`

Comment: Alright, so that's showing the GET variables rewritten correctly, but it's adding the server's root folders to the mix. So `testing.example.com/var?id=0` to `testing.example.com/var/www/testing/?test=var&id=0`

Comment: Ok you can avoid that using: `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /?api_call=$1 [L,QSA,R]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ?api_call=$1 [L,QSA]
```